# return all values from user table record

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

Let's say, I got a procedure called get_prod that returns a user-defined record:

```
create or replace package test is
    cursor cGetProducts(NROWS integer) is
        select prod.PROD_REF,
               prod.PROD_IDENT,
               prod.PROD_DESCR,
               prod.PROD_GENDATE,
               prod.PROD_GENUSERNO,
               pu.PU_LENGTH,
               pu.PU_WIDTH,
               pu.PU_HEIGHT,
               pu.PU_WEIGHT
          from product    prod,
               product_um pu
         where prod.PROD_REF = pu.PROD_REF
           and prod.PROD_UMBASE = pu.PU_UM
           and rownum <= NROWS;

    type rec_tt is record(
        prod_ref integer,
        prod_ident varchar(50),
        PROD_DESCR varchar(100),
        prod_gendate date,
        prod_genuser integer,
        prod_length number(21,6),
        prod_width number(21,6),
        prod_height number(21,6),
        prod_weight number(21,6)
    );

    type prod_t is table of rec_tt index by BINARY_INTEGER;
    
    procedure get_prod(
        MAXROWS             in      integer,
        NROWS               in      integer,
        o_table                 out prod_t
    );
end test;
/
create or replace package body test is
    procedure get_prod(
        MAXROWS             in      integer,
        NROWS               in      integer,
        o_table                 out prod_t
    )is
    begin
        if not cGetProducts%isOpen then
            open cGetProducts(NROWS);
        end if;

        fetch cGetProducts
         bulk collect into o_table;

        if cGetProducts%NotFound or MAXROWS>0 and cGetProducts%RowCount>MAXROWS then
            close cGetProducts;
        end if;
    end get_prod;
end test;
/
```

It's not a big deal to test this procedure but to see the results of the table, I had to loop over the table and write down every single parameter out of the record, like that:

```
declare
    -- Non-scalar parameters require additional processing 
    o_table TEST.PROD_T;
begin
    -- Call the procedure
    test.get_prod(
        MAXROWS => 0,
        NROWS   => 99,
        o_table => o_table);
    
    for i in 1..o_table.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line(o_table(i).prod_ref);
        dbms_output.put_line(o_table(i).prod_ident);
        ...
        ...
    end loop;
end;
```

But I would write down every single parameter of the record and fetch it. Is there an easier way to do this, especially when there are records that have much more paramters?

Comment: In SQL, result sets are unordered so  `and rownum <= NROWS` may return the first `NROWS` in a random order.

Comment: you're right, I just wanted to write a quick example

Comment: If your desire is to just write less code to see the result set then No. If however you just want to clean-up the execution section of your procedure then you can write another procedure which does the dbms_output for a single row, then call it for each row in the result set (yes that is actually more code, but a cleaner procedure). If your desire is to produce a report then (imho) you have the wrong tool. The database should serve up your data, your app's presentation layer should do the formatting and output. Pl/Sql is just not designed for reporting.

Comment: Not directly related, but there is a step wise refinement you could which could reduce maintenance. Since your record definition mirrors your cursor there is no need for it. Just  define your collection in terms of the cursor: `type prod_t is table cGetProducts%rowtype of index by BINARY_INTEGER`. With that definition any change to the cursor or the underlying data base columns are automatically picked up. You, or your successors, do not have to remember the change the record definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use database defined custom types. Those types are able to have there own methods, so you can just implement an Output-Method.

Below an example what I mean:

```
create or replace type VarcharArray_T as
table of varchar2(32767 char);


create or replace type VarcharArrayObj_T force as object
(
  -- Attributes
  Value                VarcharArray_T,
    
  -- Constructor
  constructor function VarcharArrayObj_T return self as result,
  
  -- Methods
  member procedure Output
)

create or replace type body VarcharArrayObj_T is
  
  --
  -- Constructor 
  --
  constructor function VarcharArrayObj_T
  return self as result 
  is
  begin
  
    self.Value := VarchArarray_T();
    
    return;
  end;
  
  --
  --  Prints the values to console
  --
  member procedure Output
  is
    i                             number := 0;
  begin
    i := self.Value.First();
    
    while i is not null
    loop
      -- !!! You can implement the child attribute access here once !!!
      DBMS_Output.Put_Line(self.Value(i)); 
      
      i := self.Value.Next(i);         
    end loop;
  end;
  
end;
```